# TailwindCss troubleshooting

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm having an issue where I'm using Tailwindcss in my project and it was working properly but recently my computer did an automatic reboot which deleted some files off my project including Tailwind.config. Now, I went back and installed it, made sure it was in the root directory but none of the CSS I had before is rendering on the app. is there any suggestions you guys might have? I've done all the proper steps that Tailwind DOCs has offered. Below ill show the contents of Tailwind.config and the path. TIA for any advice!

[Tailwind.config and in contents you can see the paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOMHI.png)

[This is page.tsx where I use tailwind.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xPK5.png)

I've tried and looked at tailwind docs, looked up my remote GitHub repo to see how the Tailwind.config looked like in the earlier commits before my computer rebooted but no luck, and I've also tried to look on YouTube for any tricks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your post to include code, as text, in a code tag.